# Concept of getting string from parent class to child class?

Tags: java, inheritance

How to get the string from the parent class to child class? Please check my code and let me know how to do this? I want to get the string from parent to child class.

```
public class ExtendExamle {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        File file=new File("D:\\softs\\IEDriverServer_Win32_2.42.0\\IEDriverServer.exe");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
        WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.gmail.com");
    }

    public static class Test extends ExtendExample {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

        }

   }
```

}

Comment: can you share example?

Comment: public class A{
psvm(string[] args){
webdriver dri = new InternetExplorerDriver();
dri.get("www.abc.com");
}

public class B extends A{

}
}
Now I want to get string on child class which I give on parent class and then open it on IE browser.

Comment: Can you be more clear? Post your code and html sample

Comment: If i'm understanding you correctly, the child class would be subclassing the parent class, yes? If so, the String can be inherited without any extra work, as long as the variable uses the `public` or `protected` modifier

Comment: @VinceEmigh Plz check my code and let me know how to do this? I want to get sting from parent to child classand open it on IE browser:
public class ExtendExamle{ public static void main(String[] args) { // TODO Auto-generated method stub File file=new File("D:\\softs\\IEDriverServer_Win32_2.42.0\\IEDriverServer.exe"); System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", file.getAbsolutePath()); WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(); driver.get("gmail.com"); } public static class Test extends ExtendExamle{ public static void main(String[] args) { } } }

Comment: @user2092132 Please edit your question and put the code there. It's hard to read when you post it as a comment

Comment: @VinceEmigh plz check now

Comment: @user2092132 Your code doesn't make sense. A program should only have 1 main method. Although, I think I understand what you are trying to do. I'll write an answer

Answer (score 2):

When a class extends another class, the subclass automatically inherits any visible variables (variables that are not marked `private` or have no access modifier).

```
class ParentClass {
     protected String url = "www.stackoverflow.com";
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass { //automatically inherits url
     public void run() {
          //im guessing this class is where you want to use url?
          System.out.println(url);
     }
}

//A class to start to program
class Main {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
          ChildClass child = new ChildClass();
          child.run();
     }
 }
```

ChildClass will automatically inherit the String from ParentClass, allowing you to use url within ChildClass, with no extra work.

Answer (score 0):

Add a public static method inside the parent class to return the String.

```
    public class A {
        private static String string;
        public static String getString() { return string; }
        ...
    }

    public class B extends A {
        private String string = A.getString();
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Plz check code and let me know how to do this?
public class ExtendExamle{

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  
  File file=new File("D:\\softs\\IEDriverServer_Win32_2.42.0\\IEDriverServer.exe");
  System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
  WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
  driver.get("https://www.gmail.com");
 }
 
 public static class Test extends ExtendExamle{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
   
  }
  
 }

}

Comment: @user2092132 Do not post long pieces of code in the comment section. Edit your question and include the code there, then tell the person answering to look at the edited question